# Using Microsoft Dynamics GP Web Services, how do I add a salesperson to a sales invoice?

Tags: web-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi, dynamics-gp, dynamics-gp-api

I need to add a salesperson to a GP sales invoice.  I'm using the web services command CreateSalesInvoice.  The code to create the invoice has been working for years, but I can't figure out a way to add a salesperson.  The only salesperson field I could find is under commissions, so I focused on adding a record there without success.  I also tried filling in a user defined field, but that also didn't work.

1. Adding a salesperson worked (the invoice was created; I created a territory and a salesperson in GP first), but the salesperson does not appear on the commissions area of the invoice in GP.

   ```
       SalespersonKey spk = new SalespersonKey
       {
           Id = "BobSmith"
       };
       salesInvoice.SalespersonKey = spk;
   ```
2. Tried to add a commission, but it seems to be read only.

   ```
   salesInvoice.Commissions =
   ```
3. Adding a user defined field throws an error saying UserDefined is null

   ```
   salesInvoice.UserDefined.Text01 = "Bob Smith";
   ```